# Function Returned Object could not be iterated in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, object

I would like to iterate object in Excel VBA. But it shows error "Run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method".

```html
Sub FunctionTest()
    
    Dim src, dist, production As Workbook
    Dim files As Object
    
    Set dist = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set files = getFiles(dist.path)
    
    For Each file In files
    
        Debug.Print file.Name
    
    Next
    
End Sub

Function getFiles(path As String) As Object
    
    Dim fsObject, folderObj, FileObj As Object
    
    Set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folderObj = fsObject.GetFolder(path)
    Set filesObj = folderObj.files
    
    Set getFiles = fsObject
    
End Function
```

But it works well if it is not returned object like this.

```html
Function getFiles(path As String) As Object
    
    Dim fsObject, folderObj, FileObj As Object
    
    Set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folderObj = fsObject.GetFolder(path)
    Set filesObj = folderObj.files
    
    For Each file In filesObj
    
        Debug.Print file.Name
    
    Next
    
    Set getFiles = fsObject
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is returning the wrong object. It should be:

```
 Set getFiles = filesObj
```